# Porblema con ventana nodal solo la abre una vez

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, modal

Estoy haciendo un condigo para abrir una ventana modal el problema es que solo me abre la ventana nodal en el primer registro ya que si le doy en el segundo o en cualquier otro que no sea el primero no me abre, estoy abriendo la ventana modal a través de una llamada a una clase de css y me abre bien pero solo en el primer registro en los otros registros no abre ni nada y no se si pueda ser por la manera en que abro la modal o por el ciclo foreach  a continuación el código:
Html

```
<table class="datatable display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" id="tabl_product">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Categoria producto</th>
        <th>Nombre del producto</th>
        <th>Descripción del producto</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
        <th>Imagen</th>
        <th>ACCIONES</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="producto">
      <?php
      $resultado_categoria = $categoria->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
      foreach ($resultado as $row_category) { 
         $TraerDatos_categoria=$row[0]."||".
          $row[1];
      }

      $resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH );
      foreach ($resultado as $row) { 
           $TraerDatos=$row[0]."||".
           $row[1]."||".
           $row[2]."||".
           $row[3]."||".
           $row[4]."||".
           $row[5]."||".
           $row[6];
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row["NOMBRE_CATEGORIA_PRODUCTO"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["1"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["2"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["3"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["4"] ?></td>
          <td class="imagen_vista"><?php echo '<img src="'. $row["5"] . '" style="width:140px;height:140px;border-radius:10px;background:none;">'?><td>
            <!-- Actualizar registro -->
            <button class="abrirPopup-edit btn-edit" id="actualizar_producto" onclick="llenarmodal('<?php echo $TraerDatos; ?>');">Editar</button>
            <!-- Eliminar registro -->
            <a href="<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>app/models/admin/productos/eliminar_producto.php?ID_PRODUCTO=<?php echo $row["ID_PRODUCTO"] ?>" class="obtener_eliminar"><button class="abrirPopup-edit btn-delete" type="button">Eliminar</button></a>
        </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Javascript:

```
const container_edit_product = document.getElementById("container_edit_product");
const actualizar_producto = document.getElementById("actualizar_producto");
const form_edit_product = document.getElementById("form_edit_product");
const Button_close_edit_product = document.getElementById("Button_close_edit_product");

actualizar_producto.addEventListener("click", () => {
    container_edit_product.classList.add("show");
    form_edit_product.classList.add("show");
});

Button_close_edit_product.addEventListener("click", () => {
    container_edit_product.classList.remove("show");
    form_edit_product.classList.remove("show");
});
```

Comment: Entiendo que en cada fila hay un producto con un botón para abrir la ventana, pero todos los botones tienen el mismo id, creo que deberías poner ids diferentes, con un contador por ejemplo

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices pero como podria agregar un contador al Id

Answer (score 0):

Si tus registros tienen un campo único  puedes usarlo como id de la fila.
Si no es el caso, creas el contador lo incrementas en cada iteración del bucle y luego lo usas para construir el id.
Por ejemplo:

```
    $numProd = 0;
    foreach ($resultado as $row) {
        $numProd++;
        ...
       id="actualizar_producto".$numProd
       ...
```

Luego veo que los botones (actualizar_producto) tienen dos controladores para el mismo evento: uno puesto en el HTML y otro en la parte Javascript.
Aún sin verl código de llenar_modal()cCreo que el problema está en la parte Javascript ahora mismo document.getElementById("actualizar_producto") te da el primer botón que encuentra porque los ids están repetidos.
Al modificar este id con el contador, cada botón será único y tendrás que añadir el controlador de evento a cada botón usando document.getElementById("actualizar_producto1"), document.getElementById("actualizar_producto2")...
etc.
Esto podrías hacerlo obteniedo el NodeList de botones con
document.querySelectorAll('button[id^="actualizar_producto"')

A cada elemento de este NodeList le asignas el manejador de eventos.
Esto es con lo que puedo contribuir a la vista del código publicado en la pregunta. Espero que te sirva al menos como guía.

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando `getElementById` lo que selecciona solamente un único elemento. Usar `getElementByClass` tampoco lo solucionaría. Lo que tienes que hacer usar `querySelectorAll` o usar una clase y usar `document.getElementsByClassName`. Una vez hecho eso, tendrás un array de todos los elementos, así que solo debes recorrerlo y `escuchar` el click.

```
const container_edit_product = document.getElementById("container_edit_product");
const array_actualizar_producto = document.querySelectorAll("actualizar_producto");
const form_edit_product = document.getElementById("form_edit_product");
const Button_close_edit_product = document.getElementById("Button_close_edit_product");

array_actualizar_producto.forEach(function(elemento){
  elemento.addEventListener("click", () => {
    container_edit_product.classList.add("show");
    form_edit_product.classList.add("show");
  });
})

Button_close_edit_product.addEventListener("click", () => {
    container_edit_product.classList.remove("show");
    form_edit_product.classList.remove("show");
});
```

El resto de elementos no tengo mucha información, así que no sé si son varios o es solamente uno. Edita según tus necesidades.

También puedes hacer uso del ejemplo que dijo Juan

```
document.querySelectorAll('button[id^="actualizar_producto"')
```

La cuestión es que no escuches solamente a un único elemento :).

Comment: No ya trate con lo intentado pero aun no puedo arreglarlo no se si puedan ser un poco mas claros o si tienen otra solución lo agardeceria

Comment: Tienes algún error de JS?